# Effect of where statement in subquery (to get rid of unnecessary join)

Tags: sql-server, subquery, where

Please consider the following query:

```sql
select * 
from parent p
where p.id in (
  select p.id
  from parent p
  inner join child c on c.parentId = p.id
  where p.age > 50
)
```

Is it safe (in general!) to rewrite the query to this, in order to save a join? The subquery contains the same alias as the outer query (not a typo).

```sql
select * 
from parent p
where p.id in (
  select p.id
  from child c 
  where c.parentId = p.id 
  and p.age > 50
)
```

My concerns are that the subquery's where-statement is going to be applied to the outer query's result. Is that reasoning correct?

Please note that the query above is just a simple example and the real query is big, where the sub-select is somewhere in some or-condition and contains several joins.

Comment: If `IN` is the order of the day, why not just `...WHERE p.id IN (SELECT c.parent FROM child c) AND p.age > 50`?

Comment: The suggested alternative is a correlated sub-query which is likely to be less efficient ie more costly, than a formulation using a join directly to child.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is easier to see with the aid of some rewrites. Your first query can be rewritten to (using the same alias at different levels makes it a bit difficult to understand):

```
select * 
from parent p1
where exists (
  select 1  
  from parent p2
  join child c on c.parentId = p2.id
  where p2.age > 50
    and p1.id = p2.id 
)
```

Assuming id is unique in parent this can be rewritten as:

```
select * 
from parent p1
where exists (
  select 1  
  from child c 
  where c.parentId = p1.id
    and p1.age > 50
)
```

which in turn can be rewritten to your query.

So you can eliminate the join against parent inside the sub-select. However, your second query is a bit difficult to understand as it is written. I would suggest (I'm guessing your intention)

```
select * 
from parent p1
where exists (
  select 1  
  from child c 
  where c.parentId = p1.id
)
and p1.age > 50
```

If parent.id is not unique the above wont hold

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to save a join?
this is efficient
this assume not duplicate in parent

```
select distinct p.* 
  from parent p
  join child c 
        on c.parentId = p.id 
       and p.age > 50
```

No join

```
select p.* 
  from parent p
 where exists (select 1 from child c 
                where c.parentId = p.id)
   and p.age > 50 

select p.* 
  from parent p
 where exists (select 1 from child c 
                where c.parentId = p.id
                  and p.age > 50)
```

as for alias in your query clearly the best bet is to avoid duplicate alias
otherwise just test

Comment: OP's question concerns whether parent is needed twice or if it is sufficient to access it once. You asked why a join should be saved, a then did that in all your examples which is a bit confusing (IMO)